# How to remotely replace a line in a file using sed across ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a sed command which works perflectly when run on the Linux box. This command searches for a matching pattern "AdvancedConfiguration_1" and replaces the URL statement in the next line and updates the file.

```
cd /tmp

sed -i '/AdvancedConfiguration_1/{n;s/URL=".*"/URL="http://myurl"/}' file.txt
```

My requirement is to call this command remotely from a script through ssh. However, when i try to use the command within ssh , it gives me error. I have tried using the escape sequence for double quotes and braces, but nothing seem to be working. Kindly help me fix this.

Code:

```
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@$host "sudo su - $sudo_user -c'

cd /tmp

sed -i '/AdvancedConfiguration_1/{n;s/URL=".*"/URL="http://myurl"/}' file.txt
```

' "

Error output:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{' bash: line 3:
>   s/URL=.*/URL=http://myurl/} file.txt : No such file or directory

Comment: The "code" shown there looks like it will run an ssh command first and then after that completes, run the cd and sed commands.  Based on the error output, I suspect that's not actually how it is being run.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting commands does get tricky across ssh as quotes are processed:

1. First by the local shell used to start ssh
2. Then by the remote shell used by ssh to execute the remote command

For the following command:

```
sed -i '/AdvancedConfiguration_1/{n;s/URL=".*"/URL="http://myurl"/}' file.txt
```

Try quoting as follows for use with ssh:

```
sed -i \''/AdvancedConfiguration_1/{n;s/URL=".*"/URL="http://myurl"/}'\' file.txt
```

---

**ANOTHER APPROACH**

When commands get overly complex is to create a script file on the remote side and execute it.  Here's an example that creates the script locally, uses scp to copy it over, then runs it via ssh:

```
cat >myscript <<!
sed -i '/AdvancedConfiguration_1/{n;s/URL=".*"/URL="http://myurl"/}' file.txt
!

scp myscript ...
ssh ... sh myscript
```

Be careful with the "here document" as some substitutions occur, such as environment variable evaluations.

Comment: Thanks @ash . I tried the first approach but it didn't work. I'm wondering about the second approach, because the actual file (file.txt) resides on the remote server and is accessible only by $sudo_user. I have to edit it there itself in the remote server. Hence the reason i have to do ssh and sudo su before i can do anything on the file. I'm not much familiar with "here document". Kindly help me understanding the same if you have another approach to it.

Comment: Oh ouch - that adds another "process the quotes" step.  Try adding another set of `\'` around the quoted text itself quoted, so `\\\'` ... `\\\'`.  That's three backslashes.  Another trick to help - use another command in-place of sed that lists each argument as it has been interpreted, so you can see how the final execution of the command is getting the arguments.

Comment: "Here document" is a simple way to provide input to a command inline - fed to the program as standard input.  Everything on the line after the "<<!", and up to the line with just "!" on it, is fed into the command as standard input.

Comment: The three backslashes didn't work either. Same error as above : 
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
-bash: line 2: s/URL=.*/URL=http://myurl/} file.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: OK, I didn't read the original quoting well because the formatting of the question made it look incomplete (the last line is outside the formatted code block).  I see now.  Is it necessary to quote the entire command going into ssh?  What happens if those double quotes are removed.  Note that nested double quotes only work if the nested ones are escaped (with backslash), which lead to the errors your seeing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for `sed` command, but you can try Ansible for similar tasks. It's much more easier to configure hosts through SSH. For your problem it has `lineinfile` module, just mark the string you want to edit with regexp. Probably in Ansible it looks like this:

```
- lineinfile: dest=/path/to/file.txt regexp=^URL= line=URL=http://myurl/
```

Check Ansible documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html)

Comment: Hi @cazorla, I'm not at all familiar with Ansible. Do you know of any other approach for the same? Thanks.

Comment: I mean if you execute commands through SSH constantly, CM systems is the best way to take it easier. There is a wide choice of systems: Ansible, Chef, Puppet, SaltStack. But Shell commands/scripts is a good way too, I just wished to help you as much as I can.